# Cannot send email (via GMail) with Indy. Protocol version mismatch

Tags: email, delphi, ssl, gmail, indy

I want to send an email via GMail server.

```
  TRY
    SMTP.Connect;      // <---- This is TIdSMTP
  EXCEPT
    Log.AddError('Cannot connect to the email server.');
  END;

  if SMTP.Connected then
   TRY
     SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
   EXCEPT
     on E:Exception DO
      begin
       Log.AddError('Connected to server but could not send email!');
       Log.AddError(E.Message);
      end;
   END;

 if SMTP.Connected
 then SMTP.Disconnect;
```

This piece of code worked in 2014 with Delphi XE.

The program connects to the server ok but in the end it says "SSL is not available on this server":

```
Resolving hostname smtp.Gmail.com.
Connecting to 74.125.xxx.xxx
Connected.
Connected to SMTP server...
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
SSL status: "SSLv3 write client hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
Disconnected.
Connected to server but could not send email!  
SSL is not available on this server.
```

I have the latest version of OpenSSL (downloaded today) and Delphi XE7.
The WireShark says:

> Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Protocol version)

Why I cannot send email?
I have tried all: no TSL, implicit, explicit, startTSL...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** sslvTLSv1 must be included in the `SSLIOHandler.SSLVersions` property.

Comment: ALL version can be activated (not only v1 and v3) just to be on the safe side (make sure the code works with all email servers)...

Comment: There is no `sslvSSLv1`. You are thinking of `sslvTLSv1` instead.